# Question Lag on Load, Answer & Answer Editing

Tags: support, questions

I'm using Firefox 3.5.3, trying to view questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570081/any-other-way-to-make-the-query-shorter).

Clicking the link makes Firefox freeze (can't even use other tabs), and attempts to answer or edit answers periodically hangs.  My internet connection is a 1.5 MB download - it's not like I'm trying to check questions on dialup...

I believe the periodic hangs while answering (or editing answers) is likely due to the AJAX calls to provide the banner, altering the user that the question has been closed, or someone posted an answer while the current user was typing theirs.

IME, the behavior turns up when dealing with text that has a lot of code formatting in it.

I'll try to add more examples as I come across them:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569916](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569916/match-only-if-one-field-matches-multiple-values-err/1570234#1570234)

Comment: Have you tried in **Opera?**

Comment: I don't have Opera to test with

Comment: You have cleared your cache yes?

Comment: I haven't been in the habit lately, but closing all instances & resuming provides temporary improvement.

Comment: Can you see this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: I've tried twice now, it loads without issue or hesitation.  I think the issue starts when I edit something in the thread, but I'll have to pay more attention to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this happen when you try in Chrome or Safari or a different browser?

Does it happen in Firefox safe mode?

Comment: Don't have Chrome or Safari installed.

Comment: try Firefox safe mode, then. I recommend having more than one browser installed just for testing if nothing else. Don't install Opera though, it kills small children. For fun.

Comment: Posh tosh. **Opera** kills all indiscriminately.

Comment: Firefox Safe Mode doesn't suffer, but performance is identical after resuming access with a fresh, non Safe Mode instance of Firefox.  So the cache appears to be cleared & things are OK for a while.

Comment: Last time I taunted Opera, it cured my dogs' flatulence, jaded my children & emailed compromising pictures of my wife to everyone in my address book... :)